# What is difference between if (False,) and True == (False,)

Tags: python, tuples

I learned python 3 last year, but I have barely experience.

I am reviewing about tuple again.

I would like to figure out difference between  `if (False,)` and `True == (False,)`

Since `if (False,):` is true, but `True == (False,)` is false, I am very confused.

Comment: 1. Check a `tuple` containing a Boolean value False. 2. Check a `tuple` containing a Boolean value False is equal to `True`. In both case, a Boolean value False can be integer 1, float 2.3, whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The boolean value of a tuple is `True` if it has contents, if it is empty it is `False`. Because `(False,)` is a tuple with one element it's boolean value is `True`.
2. You are comparing a `tuple` to a `bool`, that will always result in `False`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's easily understandable.

Answer (score 5):

`if` does not test for `== True`. It tests for the [*truth value*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) of an object:

> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an `if` or `while` condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below.

Objects are normally always considered *true*, except for the `False` or `None` objects (on their own), numeric zero, or an *empty* container.

`(False,)` is a tuple with one element, and any tuple that is not empty is considered a *true value*, because it is not an empty container.

You can use the [`bool()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool) to get a boolean `True` or `False` value for the truth value:

```
>>> tup = (False,)
>>> bool(tup)
True
>>> bool(tup) == True
True
```

Comment: Also, (directed to OP, not answerer, who is certainly already aware), the same is true (no pun intended) for lists: `bool([False])` will return `True`, since `[False]` is a non-empty list.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me

Comment: @WoongheeLee: Glad to have been of help, and that you found multiple answers to be helpful to you! Unfortunately, you can only mark *one* answer as accepted; pick the one you feel helped you the most, or, if you really can't pick, then not selecting any is also fine. It's all up to you! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this highlights the difference.

`if (False,):` will *evaluate* because a non-empty tuple is a truth-y value. It is not true itself. And comparing a tuple against a boolean shouldn't be expected to return true in any case, regardless of the content of said tuple.

```
t = (False,)

print(bool(t)) # True
print(t == True) # False
print(bool(t) == True) # True
```

Answer (score 1):

For any `x` whatsoever,

```
if (x,):
```

succeeds, because `(x,)` is a non-empty tuple, and all non-empty tuples evaluate to `True` in a boolean context.

And again for any `x` whatsoever,

```
if True == (x,):
```

cannot succeed, because the things being compared aren't even of the same types (for a start, `True` isn't a tuple).

In your question, what I spelled as `x` you spelled `False`, but it makes no difference what value `x` has:  `False`, `True`, the integer 42, a file object, ..., it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Not empty values are equivalent to `True` while empty values are equivalent to `False`. The tuple `(False,)` is not an empty tuple so `if (False,)` always succeeds. On the other hand `True` is not equal to the singleton tuple `(False,)` so the logical expression `True == (False,)` evaluates to `False`.